# adding two objects to get the sum of the values

Tags: javascript

hey guys l'm trying to get the sum of two values in from two different objects but l'm having a problem.
this is the current code that l have:

```
  var drinks = [
   {
       "person": "Mdu",
       "coffee": 5,
       "tea": 0,
       "water": 3
   },
   {
       "person": "Brenda",
       "coffee": 1,
       "tea": 3,
       "water": 1
   },
   {
       "person": "Lesego",
       "coffee": 0,
       "tea": 4,
       "water": 2
   }
    ];


var orangeSellers = [];

for (var type in drinks) {
    if (drinks[type].hasOwnProperty("coffee")) {
        orangeSellers.push({
            price: drinks[type].coffee
        });
    }
}
console.log(orangeSellers[1]);
```

l am suppose to get the sum of 6 when l add two coffees.
Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var drinks = [{"person":"Mdu","coffee":5,"tea":0,"water":3},{"person":"Brenda","coffee":1,"tea":3,"water":1},{"person":"Lesego","coffee":0,"tea":4,"water":2}];

var result = drinks.reduce((sum, e) => {
  return sum + e.coffee;
}, 0);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `total` variable like so:

```js
var drinks = [
   {
       "person": "Mdu",
       "coffee": 5,
       "tea": 0,
       "water": 3
   },
   {
       "person": "Brenda",
       "coffee": 1,
       "tea": 3,
       "water": 1
   },
   {
       "person": "Lesego",
       "coffee": 0,
       "tea": 4,
       "water": 2
   }
    ];
var orangeSellers = [];
var total = 0;

for (var type in drinks) {
  if (drinks[type].hasOwnProperty("coffee")) {
    orangeSellers.push({
      price: drinks[type].coffee
    });
    total += drinks[type].coffee;
  }
}

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple solution : 
No need to push to another object if you only want to get the sum

http://jsbin.com/?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

```
drinks.reduce(function (prev, next) {
  return (prev + next.coffee);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var drinks = [{
  "person": "Mdu",
  "coffee": 5,
  "tea": 0,
  "water": 3
}, {
  "person": "Brenda",
  "coffee": 1,
  "tea": 3,
  "water": 1
}, {
  "person": "Lesego",
  "coffee": 0,
  "tea": 4,
  "water": 2
}];


var orangeSellers = [];

for (var type in drinks) {
  if (drinks[type].hasOwnProperty("coffee")) {
    orangeSellers.push(drinks[type].coffee);
  }
}
console.log(orangeSellers); // [5, 1, 0]
var total = orangeSellers.reduce(function(carry, new_value) {
  return carry + new_value;
});
console.log(total); // 6
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/6vtykjg7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
var drinks = [{
   "person": "Mdu",
   "coffee": 5,
   "tea": 0,
   "water": 3
 }, {
   "person": "Brenda",
   "coffee": 1,
   "tea": 3,
   "water": 1
 }, {
   "person": "Lesego",
   "coffee": 0,
   "tea": 4,
   "water": 2
 }];
 var total = getSum("coffee")

 function getSum(obj_pro){
  var total = 0;
    for (var type in drinks) {
    if (drinks[type].hasOwnProperty(obj_pro)) {
        total += parseInt(drinks[type][obj_pro]) 
    }
  }
  return total;
 }
```

Advantage of this code is you can get sum of other properties as well

https://jsfiddle.net/84mpy08y/1/